# In 13th Age, how many attacks of opportunity can a character make in one round?

Tags: combat, opportunity-attack, 13th-age

I've been reading the core rulebook -and loving it-, and planning to run a game soon, and I'm guessing that if there's no mention of more than one attack of opportunity anywhere, it's because a player or foe can make just one in a turn.

If this is the case, is there in other book of the game, a feat or power that changes this? (as Combat Reflexes in Pathfinder).

Or am I missing something in the book? (I just have the core rulebook for now).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no limit on the number of opportunity attacks a creature can make: it's a free action, triggered by the action of an enemy, that takes place during their turn.

Answer (score 2):

## There is no limit.

A creature can make opportunity attacks as often as they are provoked, because opportunity attacks are free actions.

See the following rules excerpts from the *13th Age SRD* on [opportunity attacks](http://www.13thagesrd.com/combat-rules/#Disengaging) (emphasis mine):

> When a creature gets to make an opportunity attack, it can make a basic melee attack against that foe as a **free action** during the turn of the creature that is provoking the opportunity attack.

And on the use of [free actions](http://www.13thagesrd.com/combat-rules/#Free_Actions) (emphasis mine):

> You can take **any number** of free actions on your turn, as allowed by the GM. Creatures can also take free actions when it’s not their turn as part of a triggering condition.

The action economy does not restrict them to a limited number per round like it would if they used an interrupt action, standard action, move action, quick action.